# Calling one target from another and also pass a variable or value in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to call "target_1" from "target_2" plus also pass on a variable to the "target_1".

```
.PHONY:target_1
target_1: 
ifeq ($(RQM_SETUP),ci)
        mkdir /tmp/$1
        chown 1000:1000 /tmp/$1
else
    @echo "Nothing to do" 
endif


.PHONY:target_2
target_2: 
    $(MAKE) target_1(dags)
```

So  like in this eg, target_2 would call target_1 and also pass on value as "dags" to it.
So that it would create a "/tmp/dags" folder

Comment: There is nothing like that type of function syntax available from make command line.  Why don't you just set a variable: `$(MAKE) target_1 VAR=dags` then in your rule use `$(VAR)`?

Comment: yeah this seemed to have worked, thanks, although it created another issue for me! there was a eval defined in target_1, now i cannot access it value in target_2, creating a separate issue for the same