# Passing of variable from One Make Target to Another

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Target_2 is unable to get value of eval set in target_1,
The destination eval turns out empty handed, i.e no value is assigned to it

```
.PHONY:target_1
target_1: 
ifeq ($(RQM_SETUP),ci)
    $(eval efs-mount-path := $(shell mktemp -d))
else
    @echo "$(VAR)" 
endif


.PHONY:target_2
target_2: 
    $(MAKE) target_1 VAR=dags
    $(eval destination := $(efs-mount-path))
```

Comment: Well, sure.  By running `$(MAKE)` you're invoking a completely new instance of the make program.  Variables set in that other program aren't available in the current program.  All in all this seems like a confusing way to create a makefile but without more details about what you _really_ want to do there's not much more we can say.  It feels like you're trying to treat a makefile as if it were a procedural language, and it's not.  It's almost always a bad idea to run `eval` in a recipe, and it's usually better to avoid using recursive make if you can help it.

Comment: But, anyway, if you want to do this you'll have to run the `eval` assignment in the _parent_ makefile, then pass the value to the child when you invoke it with something like `$(MAKE) target_1 VAR=dags efs-mount-point=$(efs-mount-point)`.  Seems rickety to me.  What if someone runs `make target_1` directly?

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/63884790/425540, for me.

Comment: in the end i used the "export" to make the variable available across targets